# flot chart spacing between bars

Tags: jquery, flot

I have the following flot chart and it works perfectly but the problem is the bars should be in center to the respective column in the upper table. i used the following options in flot chart and it displays as it showed in the image. But i think this wont align properly as number of columns increases, is there other way to do this?

```
xaxis: { min: 0.5, max: (legend.maxlength + 0.5), ticks: xAxis },
```

[image: flot chart]
<sub>(source: [ravidowluri.com](http://ravidowluri.com/untitled.png))</sub>

Comment: common any one out there to help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bars look like they *are* centered on the table columns, so I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  But perhaps the bars.align option is what you're looking for?  The API docs explain this in detail, but basically your series would look like this:

```
series = {
    data = [...],
    bars: {
        align: "center"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes they are centered and i have that code already but it might be a great chance they wont align with the columns with the table in the upper section as the number of columns in that table increases. I am not sure if thats the right way to do it.

Comment: As long as you ensure that the left and right sides of the chart line up with the matching sides of the table content, I don't see why the table & chart columns wouldn't continue to line up as you add more.